# How to send data to a server each day at 23:59?

Tags: android, asynchronous, service

I have made an app with a service that is always  running in background. This service uses [AWAKE](https://awareframework.com/) framework to collect data from the smartphone sensors. What I want to do now is to send these data every day at 23:59 to a server but, how can I do it?.
Thanks!

Comment: you can use push notifications for this purpose. When you receive notification send your data to your server

Comment: you have the service already running, use the timer to check the time and send data

Comment: user alaram manager  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager

Comment: Do you need to send it at exactly that time, or just once a day?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using what Nouman Shah said in a comment.

I created a class that extends from BroadcastReceiver

[image]

and then I created an alarm using the Alarm Manager

[image]

Thanks!